# how to setup: proxy with confirmation of rules for browsing internet

Tags: debian, proxy

I'm trying to achieve something like acceptance of rules before user gets connected to the internet. For example: when users enters address http://google.com (or any other) first thing he will see is the page with short description of rules an big "Accept" and "Decline" button. When he clicks accept then the Google page appears and he can browse internet for that day, but when he clicks decline he will be redirected to internal page explaining rules. I think this could be achieved with squid but I don't know how. Any one can point me where or what to search...

Comment: Search for <del>"walled garden"</del>"captive portal".

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can try following things, then do the necessary changes as required to suit your environment.

1) Make a group of users who have accepted the T&C, let's say tc. Also let's assume that you are using IP address to keep a track of users who has accepted T&C and keeping 1 ip address per line in /etc/squid/tc.txt

2) make an acl using /etc/squid/tc.txt

3) Have you first acl as "if user's ip is not in tc.txt file, redirect request to the webpage which you want him to show." you might need to write a small script which will work as `url_rewrite_program`.

4) The moment they accept, run server side script to add IP of user in tc.txt

5) Make sure your script is intelligent enough to not to add duplicate entry in tc.txt.